# Serilizer type needed for sending ProducerRecord in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring kafka (KafkaTemplate) to send a string messages. But to make it compatible with old code, I need to attach extra CorrelationId in the message. so I create ProducerRecord object with my message as its value, and setting CorrelationId in its HeaderRecord.

```
        producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
            kafkaTemplate_.getDefaultTopic(),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            myStringMessage,
            Collections.singletonList(new RecordHeader("CorrelationID", someIdAsBytes)));
    kafkaTemplate_.sendDefault(producerRecord);
```

The key and value serializer is set as StringSerializer, but the about code failes saying something like ProduderRecord is not of type String or StringSerializer.

If I do toString() like below, it works. But then at the MessageListener side, the received ConsumerRecord does not have the correlationId as its RecordHeader because correlationId is attached as RecordHeader for ProducerRecord. So I have to do type casting on MessageListener `onMessage(Object msg)` like cast from Object to ConsumerRecord (which is a string serialized version of ProduderRecord), parse ProducerRecord from ConsumerRecord.value() field, then get the CorrelationId from ProcuderRecord header, and myStringMessage from ProducerRecord. This looks cumbersome. Is my logic of sending and receiving ok?

```
kafkaTemplate_.sendDefault(producerRecord.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing a difference between:

```
/**
 * Send the data to the default topic with no key or partition.
 * @param data The data.
 * @return a Future for the {@link SendResult}.
 */
ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> sendDefault(V data);
```

and

```
/**
 * Send the provided {@link ProducerRecord}.
 * @param record the record.
 * @return a Future for the {@link SendResult}.
 * @since 1.3
 */
ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(ProducerRecord<K, V> record);
```

Look, you have a `topic` property in the `ProducerRecord`, so, no reason to think about `sendDefault()` at all. Plus as you see it is confusing you.

Comment: since my ProducerRecord has topic in it, I can send using send(ProducerRecord<K, V> record) method instead of sendDefault(). Got it!. But I doubt even the send() method would let me send ProducerRecord without casting to String.

Comment: do you know if I do send(producerRecord), what type of key and value serializer I should configure?

Comment: Well, you must not cast at all. That was the matter of the `value`, but now you have a fully configured `ProducerRecord`. The `key/value` serializers have to be configured anyway. I don't know what is your requirement. Just imagine you send without headers! Although I see you have `myStringMessage`. So, indeed the `valueSerializer` must be string one.

Comment: Changing from sendDefault to send method worked, with StringSerializer itself. You identified my confusion. thanks Artem.